# Determining substitution method or Integration by parts

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Harry claims that the substitution method works for the following problem. Is he correct? If yes, solve the problem, if no, what method could you use. $\int x^2 e^{x^2} dx$.

Sorry for the formatting of the question. I have tried accomplishing this problem through substitution and clearly, it is not working. Would integration by parts work for this problem? Please help me figure this out and a reason as to why it would work or would not work would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: As I see this is (at least) the second post you have made in the last 30 minutes, I just want to inform you that this isn't a site for users to write their homework up for others to do for them.

Comment: I am not asking anybody to do my homework for me @ WaveX, i am asking for help with guidance

Comment: What have you tried to substitute? $u=x^2$?

Comment: AHusain, substitution method works for this problem if the question presented a e^x^3 but somehow it does not work for e^x^2 because of the presence of x^2

Answer (score 1):

That function has not an elementary primitive. Although, you can integrate over $\mathbb R$. Are you sure you didn't miss the interval of integration?

Comment: chilean, no I did not miss the interval of integration.

Answer (score 0):

Integration by parts works if you happen to know an antiderivative of $e^{x^2}$ (see the [erfi function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Erfi.html)).